# Automatic Refresh of TableView not Working

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios7, refresh

I logged into my viewDidLoad of a ViewController that has a NSTimer to start the Automatic Refresh TableView I entered every 5 seconds.

Why does not happen automatically refresh every 5 seconds as set nell'NSTimer in viewDidLoad? Where is the error?

Thanks to all

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(reloadDataTableView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)reloadDataTableView {

    [self.FFTableViewFindUser reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in reloadDataTableView to see if it's actually being called? If it is being called, is self.FFTableViewFindUser nil?

Comment: I tried to set a breakpoint on the void reload and after 5 seconds the app crashes then the NSTimer does the problem is that the tableView does not update ... from what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you saying your application crashes when you put breakpoint on your selector method of nstimer that means you tableView is getting reloaded but make sure your datasource array of your table view is changing after every 5 second which you are displaying in the the cellForRow try to print the datasource array in the console when the reloadDataTableView is called and see if your dataSource is changing.
put breakpoint at cellForRow and check whether control goes to that method after every 5Scond if its goes inside that means your datasource array which you are displaying in cellForRow is not getting updated